# Are there any document icons for the qgis mimetype?

Tags: qgis

In a default Ubuntu install (QGIS 1.8.0) no document icon is associated with the mimetype 'application/x-qgis-project'.  As a consequence every saved QGIS document is interpreted by the OS as being a text or xml document and the icon displayed gives no indication it has anything to do with QGIS.

I've googled around and can't find anything; I could make an icon set myself but wanted to see if I'm just missing something before doing it..

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 11.10, this is the icon that is displayed after the default install:

[image]

So the icon has to be somewhere. Searching Github or asking the devs seem to be your options.

Comment: Ahh, it's called 'qgis-mime-icon.png' and it *was* installed with my default install, just not correctly associated for some reason.  Thanks for the suggestion to look at github, which led me to it..